# Retrieving first-recorded ejection fraction value

Tags: mimic-iii

I want to retrieve the the first recorded ejection fraction (EF) of patients. From my attempts, the codes `2697`, `2699`, `226272`, and `227008` represent ejection fractions:

```
SELECT itemid, label, abbreviation, linksto, category, unitname
FROM d_items
WHERE itemid IN ('2697', '2699', '226272', '227008');
```

...which gives:

```
 itemid |       label       |   abbreviation    |   linksto   |        category        | unitname
--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+------------------------+----------
   2697 | EF %              |                   | chartevents |                        |
   2699 | EF                |                   | chartevents |                        |
 226272 | EF (CCO)          | EF (CCO)          | chartevents | Hemodynamics           | %
 227008 | Ejection Fraction | Ejection Fraction | chartevents | Scores - APACHE IV (2) | %
```

To extract the values of EF, I use:

```
SELECT subject_id, hadm_id, icustay_id, itemid, charttime, value, valuenum
FROM
(
    SELECT * 
    , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY chartevents.subject_id ORDER BY chartevents.charttime) as charttime_id_order
    FROM chartevents
    WHERE itemid IN ('2697', '2699', '226272', '227008')
) AS tbl_ef
WHERE charttime_id_order=1
```

...which returns the following:

```
 subject_id | hadm_id | icustay_id | itemid |      charttime      | value | valuenum
------------+---------+------------+--------+---------------------+-------+----------
        711 |  158767 |     270525 | 227008 | 2185-03-23 14:45:00 | 45    |       45
       1581 |  113063 |     217900 |   2699 | 2171-11-13 00:30:00 | 32    |       32
       2638 |  135772 |     264212 |   2699 | 2138-10-02 04:30:00 | 40    |       40
       9767 |  195886 |     277000 |   2699 | 2154-11-13 20:30:00 | 35    |       35
      14135 |  196667 |     238064 |   2699 | 2136-09-15 21:00:00 | 16    |       16
      14588 |  177135 |     270609 |   2699 | 2187-12-03 08:00:00 | 44    |       44
      15145 |  142200 |     248846 |   2697 | 2162-09-18 01:00:00 | 31    |       31
      16630 |  136282 |     264249 |   2699 | 2108-01-22 12:00:00 | 26    |       26
      28426 |  153325 |     245963 | 227008 | 2124-01-10 14:32:00 | 0     |        0
      40094 |  193368 |     210633 | 226272 | 2147-11-23 17:30:00 | 46    |       46
      43961 |  150566 |     247783 | 226272 | 2120-07-02 20:22:00 | 42    |       42
      52532 |  124500 |     255738 | 226272 | 2195-02-05 19:53:00 | 31    |       31
      54187 |  116451 |     246413 | 226272 | 2112-04-29 20:48:00 | 58    |       58
      63961 |  160874 |     284945 | 226272 | 2140-08-11 20:28:00 | 54    |       54
      71243 |  124711 |     243996 | 226272 | 2140-06-04 07:47:00 | 35    |       35
      78419 |  126041 |     203258 | 226272 | 2179-06-07 03:36:00 | 39    |       39
      81087 |  106452 |     228342 | 226272 | 2155-05-21 07:43:00 | 20    |       20
      86155 |  145282 |     296472 | 226272 | 2190-10-28 09:00:00 | 38    |       38
      89356 |  159967 |     256091 | 226272 | 2104-12-02 09:00:00 | 35    |       35
      96218 |  122615 |     275009 | 226272 | 2187-10-14 14:00:00 | 36    |       36
      97539 |  178571 |     215558 | 226272 | 2139-11-08 18:06:00 | 36    |       36
(21 rows)
```

The result set is ridiculously small. Am I doing something wrong or are EF values stored somewhere else as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejection fraction values are contained within the echodiagram notes. To get the text of the echodiagram notes, use the following:

```
SELECT subject_id, hadm_id
    , category
    , text
FROM noteevents
    WHERE category='Echo'
    AND hadm_id IS NOT NULL
```

The `charttime` values for most records is blank, so you will have to get the values from the echodiagram text itself. Use the following:

```
SELECT subject_id, hadm_id
    , PARSE_DATETIME (
    '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S',
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', chartdate)
    || REGEXP_EXTRACT(noteevents.text, 'Date/Time: .+? at ([0-9]+:[0-9]{2})')
    || ':00') AS regex_charttime
    , category
    , text
FROM noteevents
    WHERE category='Echo'
    AND hadm_id IS NOT NULL
```

Now that we have the text of the echodiagram notes and when they were taken, we can rank the `charttime` values to determine the first echodiagram note:

```
WITH ef_regex_charttime AS (
   SELECT subject_id, hadm_id
   , PARSE_DATETIME (
         '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S',
         FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', chartdate)
         || REGEXP_EXTRACT(noteevents.text,
            'Date/Time: .+? at ([0-9]+:[0-9]{2})')
         || ':00'
      ) AS regx_charttime
   , category
   , text
   FROM noteevents
   WHERE category='Echo'
   AND hadm_id IS NOT NULL
)

, ef_rank_charttime AS (
   SELECT *
   , RANK() OVER (
       PARTITION BY ef_regex_charttime.subject_id
       ORDER BY ef_regex_charttime.regx_charttime
    ) as ejectionf_time_id_order
   FROM ef_regex_charttime
)

, ef AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM ef_rank_charttime
   WHERE ejectionf_time_id_order = 1 -- FIRST ECHODIAGRAM
)

SELECT * FROM ef;
```

The above may not be the most optimal query but it gets the job done. After this step, you will have to use Regex to get the actual values (or value ranges) for the ejection fractions.

Please see the [R ejection fraction extraction function](https://github.com/vincentmajor/mimicfilters/blob/b6903be8cf89ceb53f15d70919db6874d9a0befe/R/extract_ejection_fraction.R#L137) by [vincentmajor](https://github.com/vincentmajor) on GitHub.